# Node JS Template Add Object To Window

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nunjucks

I was wondering if there was a way, when rendering a javascript template with Node, to attach an object or values to the window object. For example, if I wanted to take the data that was passed to the res.render function and attach it to the window object for later use. Later use would be for hash routing. Currently I am using [Nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/).

```
res.render('index', {data:{name:'Max'}});
// How could  I attach data to the window object for later use.
```

Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I didn't make this clear, but when I was referring the the window object, I was referring to the client window object. Not a window object in Node. When rendering the template how can I add items to the window object.

Comment: Are you sure there is a window object in Node.js?

Comment: The window object on the front end. When rendering the template. I guess I didnt make that clear

Comment: I am assuming you mean the window object for client? If so you need to send the data to the client or template.

Comment: ^there isn't. I assume he means the client side window object, and if so you can't do this from a template but you could do it from client side javascript.

Comment: I added a comment to make it clear.@KrisHollenbeck, how can I do this when rendering the template?

Comment: @MaxBaldwin, What templating are you using? EJS, Jade, other?

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck Nunjucks, as stated above

Comment: Your code renders the template server side so what you're asking for is impossible. I think what you want is to persist some state information on the browser side. Is that right? There are many ways to do that, some are better than others depending on what problem you're solving. Can you elaborate more on what you're trying to do?

Comment: I don't know nunjucks, and maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do, but does something like `<script>window.nameFromTemplate = {{data.name}}</script>` fit what you're looking for? That's really ugly, though, and @AndrewLavers is probably right hat there's a clear way to accomplish whatever high-level task you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hey @AndrewLavers, thanks for commenting. I have a page that is rendered with Nunjucks that has a user information template passed to it. I want to take that information and attach it to the window object, so that I dont have to render a new page when the user clicks on a link. I want to use hash routing without having to render the page or query the server again.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin, Sorry I missed that. Have you seen this? https://github.com/mkoryak/nunjucks-script-tag Sorry, I haven't used nunjucks much. But this might be useful.

Comment: That is a great find @KrisHollenbeck. I am going to try this on my template and report back to you. If it works, you should submit this as an answer. It isn't exactly what I want, but I think it is the only work around. Thanks!

Comment: While this should work, I would warn that polluting your global namespace by putting a script tag inside a template is a big dirty hack. I don't have enough chars here to explain why this is a bad idea. The problem you're describing is a single page app, and there are much better ways to do it. For example, defining a User model in your client side javascript and fetching the data with an ajax call. AngularJS or Backbone are good options here.

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck, great find but it didnt work as planned. Doing window.user = {{ user }} did not work. Nunjucks sees it as [object Object]]

Comment: What about `window.user = {{ user[0] }}`? Or maybe something with the `{{ }}` template syntax is throwing it off?

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck I am thinking that it has something to do with the {{}}. user[0] would return undefined because it is an object, not an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render an inline script right to the html output:

```
<body>
<script>
window.data = {name: 'Max'};
</script>
</body>
```

But adding properties to global object is not recommended, better use a namespace like:

```
var app = {};
app.data = {name: 'Max'};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tried this with Nunjucks. Doesn't work this simply.

Comment: It should work with any templating engine that can pass variables to the view.

Answer (score -2):

In node GLOBAL object is equivalent to window object in DOM scripting. Assign it to GLOBAL object. Refer the link below for more info about GLOBAL object in node.
http://www.hacksparrow.com/global-variables-in-node-js.html

Comment: Hey Luke, thanks for the comment. I was actually referring to when the template is being rendered. The client side window, not the  global node object.

Comment: Then we can achieve it by writing an ajax call to the api. The api should be delivering you the data to be assigned to window object and you will be assigning the value returned there to the window object. You will need create an api to be called to get the data to be set.